# Neural Network trained using back propagation solves AND , Or but doesn't solve XOR

Tags: neural-network, backpropagation

I have implemented back propagation algorithm to train my neural network. It solves AND & OR perfectly, but when I try to train to solve XOR, the total error is really high.

The network topology for XOR network is : 2 neurons at input layer, 2 neurons at the hidden layer, and one neuron at the output layer.

I'm using sigmoid as my activation function, and weighted sum as input.

Here is the part of my code responsible for back propagation:

```
  protected void updateOutputLayer(double[] outputErr)
    {

        double delta;
        Neuron neuron;
        double errorDerivative;
        for ( int i=0;i<this.getNeuralNetwork().getOutputLayer().getSize();i++)
        {
            neuron=this.getNeuralNetwork().getOutputLayer().getAt(i);
            errorDerivative=neuron.getTransferFunction().getDerivative(neuron.getNetInput());
            delta=outputErr[i]*errorDerivative;
            neuron.setDelta(roundThreeDecimals(delta));
            // now update the weights

            this.updateNeuronWeights(neuron);
        }

    }
   protected void updateHiddenLayerNeurons()
    {

        List<Layer> layers=this.network.getLayers();
        Layer currentLayer;
        double neuronErr;
        for ( int i=layers.size()-2;i>0;i--)
        {
            currentLayer= layers.get(i);

            for (int j=0;j<currentLayer.getSize();j++)
            {
                neuronErr=calculateHiddenLayerError(currentLayer.getAt(j));

                currentLayer.getAt(j).setDelta(neuronErr);
                this.updateNeuronWeights(currentLayer.getAt(j));
            }

        }
        //System.out.println("*****************************************");
    }
  protected double calculateHiddenLayerError(Neuron node)
    {
        List<Connection> outputCon= node.getOutputConnections();
        double errFactor=0;
        for (Connection outputCon1 : outputCon) {
            //System.out.println("output od dst: "+outputCon1.getDst().getOutput());
           // System.out.println("w dst: "+outputCon1.getWeight());
            //System.out.println("in CalcErr Factor err: "+outputCon.get(i).getDst().getError()+" w: "+outputCon.get(i).getWeight());
            errFactor += outputCon1.getDst().getDelta() * outputCon1.getWeight();
        }
        double derivative= node.getTransferFunction().getDerivative(node.getNetInput());

        return roundThreeDecimals(derivative*errFactor);
    }
     public void updateNeuronWeights(Neuron neuron)
{
    double weightChange;
    double input, error;
    for (Connection con: neuron.getInConnections())
    {   
        input=con.getInput();
       // System.out.println("input: "+input);
        error = neuron.getDelta();
        weightChange=this.learningRate*error*input;// error here is : output error * error derivative

        con.setWeight(roundThreeDecimals(con.getWeight()+weightChange));

    }
    // now update bias
    if(neuron.isBiasUsed())
    {
        //System.out.println("old bias: "+neuron.getBias());
        double biasChange=neuron.getBias()+neuron.getDelta()*this.learningRate;
        //System.out.println("new bias: "+biasChange);
       neuron.setBias(roundThreeDecimals(biasChange));
    }

}
```

I'm using a learning rate in the range [0.01,0.5]. Can anyone tell me what is wrong with my code?

Comment: Not sure, but might be a duplicate of [Understanding Neural Network Backpropagation](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2190732/11683)

Comment: Have you tried with 3 (or more) neurons in the hidden layer? I seem to recall something about AND, OR and XOR from my ai class, but that was a long time ago.

Comment: @watery I tried with 3 but no improvement, I will try with higher number

Comment: Well, if that didn't work then I'm probably wrong :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TL;DR:** You should update the bias with retropropagation in the very same way that weights are learned.

---

For sure, the bias plays a big role in learning the XOR compared to the OR or the AND (see [Why is a bias neuron necessary for a backpropagating neural network that recognizes the XOR operator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8039313/why-is-a-bias-neuron-necessary-for-a-backpropagating-neural-network-that-recogni) ). Hence, the bias might be the culprit.

You say `I'm using sigmoid as my activation function, and weighted sum as input`. **You need a bias than can be learned in the very same way that weights are learned.** 
Note: the bias shall be added in the summation, before applying the activation function.