# Multi-layer neural network back-propagation formula (using stochastic gradient descent)

Tags: python, machine-learning, neural-network, backpropagation, gradient-descent

Using the notations from [Backpropagation calculus | Deep learning, chapter 4](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tIeHLnjs5U8), I have this back-propagation code for a 4-layer (i.e. 2 hidden layers) neural network:

```
def sigmoid_prime(z): 
    return z * (1-z)  # because σ'(x) = σ(x) (1 - σ(x))

def train(self, input_vector, target_vector):
    a = np.array(input_vector, ndmin=2).T
    y = np.array(target_vector, ndmin=2).T

    # forward
    A = [a]  
    for k in range(3):
        a = sigmoid(np.dot(self.weights[k], a))  # zero bias here just for simplicity
        A.append(a)

    # Now A has 4 elements: the input vector + the 3 outputs vectors

    # back-propagation
    delta = a - y
    for k in [2, 1, 0]:
        tmp = delta * sigmoid_prime(A[k+1])
        delta = np.dot(self.weights[k].T, tmp)  # (1)  <---- HERE
        self.weights[k] -= self.learning_rate * np.dot(tmp, A[k].T)
```

It works, but:

- the accuracy at the end (for my use case: MNIST digit recognition) is just ok, but not very good.
  **It is much better (i.e. the convergence is much better) when the line (1) is replaced by**:

  ```
  delta = np.dot(self.weights[k].T, delta)  # (2)
  ```
- the code from [Machine Learning with Python: Training and Testing the Neural Network with MNIST data set](https://www.python-course.eu/neural_network_mnist.php) also suggests:

  ```
  delta = np.dot(self.weights[k].T, delta)
  ```

  instead of:

  ```
  delta = np.dot(self.weights[k].T, tmp)
  ```

  (With the notations of this article, it is:

  ```
  output_errors = np.dot(self.weights_matrices[layer_index-1].T, output_errors)
  ```

  )

These 2 arguments seem to be concordant: code (2) is better than code (1).

However, the math seem to show the contrary (see [video here](https://youtu.be/tIeHLnjs5U8?t=387); another detail: note that my loss function is multiplied by 1/2 whereas it's not on the video):

[image]

**Question: which one is correct: the implementation (1) or (2)?**

---

In LaTeX:

```
$$C = \frac{1}{2} (a^L - y)^2$$
$$a^L = \sigma(\underbrace{w^L a^{L-1} + b^L}_{z^L}) = \sigma(z^L)$$
$$\frac{\partial{C}}{\partial{w^L}} = \frac{\partial{z^L}}{\partial{w^L}} \frac{\partial{a^L}}{\partial{z^L}} \frac{\partial{C}}{\partial{a^L}}=a^{L-1} \sigma'(z^L)(a^L-y)$$
$$\frac{\partial{C}}{\partial{a^{L-1}}} = \frac{\partial{z^L}}{\partial{a^{L-1}}} \frac{\partial{a^L}}{\partial{z^L}} \frac{\partial{C}}{\partial{a^L}}=w^L \sigma'(z^L)(a^L-y)$$
$$\frac{\partial{C}}{\partial{w^{L-1}}} = \frac{\partial{z^{L-1}}}{\partial{w^{L-1}}} \frac{\partial{a^{L-1}}}{\partial{z^{L-1}}} \frac{\partial{C}}{\partial{a^{L-1}}}=a^{L-2} \sigma'(z^{L-1}) \times w^L \sigma'(z^L)(a^L-y)$$
```

Comment: What do you mean by "correct" exactly? Why do you think only one of them can be correct?

Comment: @Goyo: solution (1) seems to be coherent with the math (partial derivative computations, stochastic gradient descent), but the result is not so good. Solution (2) gives far better result (for an identical neural network, a very standard one for digit recognition) AND is the one that I found in the implementation I linked (see URL). But it does not seem to be coherent with the partial derivatives... thus the question: why is (2) better? Is it a well known trick? Or just random experimental observations "that work" so we use it.

Comment: Las time I checked nobody really knew why some things worked and some others didn't or why in some cases and not in other cases. It was all hit-and-miss. Intuition based on biology, physics or mathematics served as inspiration but strictly following those intuitions wouldn't always yield the best results. Maybe the previous chapters explain why Bernd Klein chose that implementation. If not you might want to ask him.

Comment: Yes maybe... do you confirm @Goyo that the math would be more in favour of (1) or did I do a mistake?

Comment: I am afraid I am not qualified to answer that question. But Bernd Klein's web has an explanation of the back-propagation algorithm. Surprisingly you do not mention it in the question. Do you think it is consistent with his implementation? With the explanations in the video? Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I spent two days to analyze this problem, I filled a few pages of notebook with partial derivative computations... and I can confirm:

- the maths written in LaTeX in the question **are correct**
- the **code (1) is the correct one**, and it agrees with the math computations:

  ```
  delta = a - y
  for k in [2, 1, 0]:
      tmp = delta * sigmoid_prime(A[k+1])
      delta = np.dot(self.weights[k].T, tmp)
      self.weights[k] -= self.learning_rate * np.dot(tmp, A[k].T)
  ```
- **code (2)** is wrong:

  ```
  delta = a - y
  for k in [2, 1, 0]:
      tmp = delta * sigmoid_prime(A[k+1])
      delta = np.dot(self.weights[k].T, delta)  # WRONG HERE
      self.weights[k] -= self.learning_rate * np.dot(tmp, A[k].T)
  ```

  and there a slight mistake in [Machine Learning with Python: Training and Testing the Neural Network with MNIST data set](https://www.python-course.eu/neural_network_mnist.php):

  ```
  output_errors = np.dot(self.weights_matrices[layer_index-1].T, output_errors)
  ```

  should be

  ```
  output_errors = np.dot(self.weights_matrices[layer_index-1].T, output_errors * out_vector * (1.0 - out_vector))
  ```

Now the difficult part that took me days to realize:

- Apparently the code (2) has a far better convergence than code (1), that's why I mislead into thinking code (2) was correct and code (1) was wrong
- ... But in fact that's just a *coincidence* because the `learning_rate` was set **too low**. Here is the reason: when using code (2), the parameter `delta` is growing much faster (`print np.linalg.norm(delta)` helps to see this) than with the code (1).
- Thus "incorrect code (2)" just compensated the "too slow learning rate" by having a bigger `delta` parameter, and it lead, in some cases, to an apparently faster convergence.

Now solved!